# How to get touched x and y of a bitmap in pixel which is in a custom GlSurfaceview ?

Tags: android

I want to get touched x and y of a bitmap and i found a solution here :

[How to convert coordinates of the image view to the coordinates of the bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933612/how-to-convert-coordinates-of-the-image-view-to-the-coordinates-of-the-bitmap)

but it doesn't work in opengl custom view

i use [harsim page curl library](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl)

could any one tell me what's wrong in using the above solution in custom OpenGl view ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`glReadPixels(int x, int y, int width, int height, int format, int type, Buffer pixels)`
, for every version of OpenGL in android. Obviously call this in the GL thread. Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802266/how-to-use-glreadpixels-with-android-usually-get-zeros) question for more example.

Comment: this example is about using glreadpixels to return colors of the pixel but i want the original x and y of the image in this glsurfaceview.